# "cannot open shared object file," but it exists

Tags: c++, .so

I'm having trouble finding why this library (matio) isn't working for me. In my Makefile I have this:

```
LIBS += -L/home/brian/.../matio-1.5.6/src/.libs/ -lmatio
```

When I attempt to run my code (links fine) I get this error:

> error while loading shared libraries: libmatio.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

libmatio.so.4 exists in the directory specified by the -L flag.

I built the library and it seems to go through `make check` with only a handful writing errors (which is fine as I only need it for reading).

Things I've tried:

- Specifying the name (i.e. `-l:libmatio.so.4.0.2`)
- Adding the path to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`
- Adding the path as a line in `/etc/ld.so.conf` and run `sudo ldconfig`
- Adding a new file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` with the path and run `sudo ldconfig`

(When I run `ldconfig -p | grep matio` nothing returns. Am I doing something wrong with `ldconfig`?)

Comment: I've gotten it to run with libmatio.a, but still don't know why the .so won't work.

Comment: have you found a solution to this problem ?

Comment: I just used the workaround mentioned above. The answer below I'm guessing is pointing to the solution, but I never found it.

Answer (score 9):

The error is *actually* telling you "no compatible library with that name exists in the library cache", not "no file with that filename exists on disk".

So, confusingly, this can happen when the shared object file is in the wrong format.

Ensure that it was built for the right platform by the right compiler! You can have a look with `file` and verify that the dynamic link is failing using `ldd` on your executable.

Comment: I built the library, and as far as I can tell it was done correctly.  `ldd` shows: `libmatio.so.4 => not found.`  Any tips on how to examine what's wrong with it?

Comment: @brian: How are your file permissions looking?

Comment: @brian: Yeah but you're missing something so why not show us what the file permissions are we can tell _you_ whether they're correct :P

Comment: Right, `-rwxrwxr-x 1 brian brian  934782 Mar  9 11:30 libmatio.so.4.0.2`

Comment: Are your (possible) library version symlinks correct? What if you rename your library to libmatio.so without any version identifiers and link to that?